# ROSCon 2014 videos Here

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking at http://vimeo.com/osrfoundation/videos and http://roscon.ros.org/2014/program/ for videos.

The composite split-screen with presenter and presentation videos side-by-side videos are nice, but if they are taking a long time to produce it would be great to have the source videos of just the presenter or just the slides with audio, especially where there is already a pdf of the slides.

---

Now available

https://vimeo.com/album/3053172

---

Edit made just to popup

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193306/roscon-2014-videos-here/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The AV company at the Palmer House is generating the post-production videos for us, but they had a bit of a technical problem in one of the talks that took a few days to get straightened out. They shipped a hard drive with all of the completed videos to OSRF, and its delivery is expected to arrive any day now. So the videos should be up very soon!

Sorry for the delay!

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-09-24**:
I see some or all are on https://vimeo.com/osrfoundation now, thanks!